# 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.ni.dll Memory stream is not expandable

Tags: c#, windows-10

I am getting the error "Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.ni.dll Memory stream is not expandable" when trying to serialize and save an instance of a custom class object.

Here are my saving/loading methods:

```
    public void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
    {
        if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // convert string to stream
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
                MemoryStream fileNameStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

                serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                stream.Position = 0;
                xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                xmlDocument.Save(fileNameStream);
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(TAG + serializableObject.ToString() + " saved");
    }


    public T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

        T objectOut = default(T);

        try
        {
            string attributeXml = string.Empty;

            // convert string to stream
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(stream);
            string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

            using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                Type outType = typeof(T);

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(read))
                {
                    objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    reader.Dispose();
                }

                read.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        if (objectOut != null) Debug.WriteLine(TAG + objectOut.ToString() + " loaded");

        return objectOut;
    }
```

And here is the object class that I'm trying to save:

```
public class EntryDataType
{
    readonly string TAG = "EntryDataType: ";

    private static int idCounter = -1;
    public int id;
    private EntryDataType parentEdt;
    public EntryDataType parentEdtProperty
    {
        get { return parentEdt; }
        set { parentEdt = value; }
    }

    // row control is not serializable, so ignore it when saving
    [XmlIgnore]
    public RowControl linkedRowControl;
    public int indent = -1;
    public int index = -1;
    public int linearIndex = -1;
    private bool completed = false;
    public bool completedProperty {
        get { return completed; }
        set
        {
            // set hidden state and set all children's hidden state, i.e. they will do the same
            completed = value;
            foreach (var item in childList)
            {
                item.linkedRowControl.SetCompleted(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public ChildList<EntryDataType> childList;
    public bool bulletButtonChecked;
    public string textboxText;

    public EntryDataType()
    {
        // assign unique id to each entry
        id = idCounter;
        idCounter++;

        //Debug.WriteLine(TAG + "new entry " + id + " created");

        childList = new ChildList<EntryDataType>();
        childList.parentEdtOfChildListProperty = this;
    }

}
```

I've already rewritten the class to eliminate it's constructor's parameters, and to ignore the unserializeable RowControl member. I am just learning .NET and c# so don't fully know what I'm doing yet; any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: `byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);` - this creates a byte array of the characters that make up the file name - probably not what you want here.

Comment: Agreed with @500-InternalServerError. You can try using the default constructor, which has an expandable store: https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ad966f9s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense, maybe a stupid question, but if I just use the default constructor then how do I load my data back up with a new stream if it's not saved with a filename handle?

Comment: Not a stupid question, to get the data, normally you would just read the stream (using e.g. `StreamReader`) or you could use the `GetBuffer` method of the `MemoryStream`. It looks, however, as if you're trying to save into a file. Why not use a `FileStream`, or [this oveload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22.aspx) of `XmlDocument.Save`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I see what you are trying to do - serialize and deserialize an object to/from a file. Your way is a bit complicated, it could be simplified, for example like this:

```
public static void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
{
    if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}


public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

There is no need to read/write to a `MemoryStream` first. You can serialize and deserialize straight from the file.

Also, when using `using`, there is no need to dispose the object (like your `stream.Dispose();` line) - that's what the dispose is for (with the added bonus that if there's an exception, the object will be disposed as well).

I haven't tried this with your class but it should work fine. Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think this is going to work. I had a hard time finding a straight forward example of how to serialize an object to/from a file until your example. Thanks so much again for the help :)

Comment: Now I'm running into further problems with file permissions, which this `File.SetAttributes(fileName, System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal);` line seemed to fix, and the file not actually being saved to the folder, but I'll hit the documentation and try and figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem. Remeber to check your debugging output for exceptions. See what you can find out and, if you're still stuck, try asking another question.

Answer (score -1):

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
MemoryStream fileNameStream = new MemoryStream();

...

xmlDocument.Save(fileNameStream);
```